# Non-printing character in .htaccess file generated by Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I have been experimenting with Zend Framework 1.12.9 and noticed that the .htaccess file it creates in the "public" folder contains a non-printing character (\x02). The ZF code that creates the file is

```php
// excerpt from:
// Zend\Tool\Project\Context\Zf\HtaccessFile.php

    public function getContents()
    {
        $output = <<<EOS

RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

EOS;
        return $output;
    }
```

and the resulting file looks like this:

[image: npp.png]

I suspect that it is just a typo in the PHP code, but I must confess that I'm not sufficiently familiar with mod_rewrite directives to know what it is trying to do. (I'm a bit puzzled by the double colons, too.)

My little test site seems to work okay, so if it is an error it's apparently not a catastrophic one. Still, I'd appreciate any insight on what that \x02 might be doing there.

### Edit

If it is in fact a case of the Heredoc block converting `\2` into \x02 in the output file then can someone confirm that the following rewrite block makes sense?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

I understand from the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that `$1, $2, ...` are "RewriteRule backreferences" and `%1, %2, ...` are "RewriteCond backreferences" but I see no mention of backslash serving any purpose other than as the escape character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that in Heredoc `\2` needs to be used as `\\2`.

**But you can use single quote at the [Nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) start to avoid escaping `\2`**:

```
$output = <<<'EOS'
...
EOS;
```

[As per PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> **Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to
>   double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc,
>   but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc.** The construct is ideal for
>   embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for
>   escaping.

---

#### UPDATE:

You asked question about use of `\2` in this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

- You can use `$1` captured from `RewriteRule` in your `RewriteCond` because `mod_rewrite` actually **processes a ruleset backwards**. It starts with the pattern in the `RewriteRule`, and if it matches, goes on to check the one or more `RewriteCond`.
- So as you can see in a `RewriteCond`, the LHS (test string) can use backreference variables e.g. `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` etc but RHS side i.e. condition string **cannot use** these `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` variables.
- Inside the RHS condition part only backreference we can use are **internal back-references** i.e. the groups we have captured in this condition itself. They are denoted by `\1`, `\2` etc.
- In your `RewriteCond` first captured group is `(/.+)`, that will be represented by internal back-reference `\1` and next captured group `(.+)` will be used as internal back-reference `\2`.
- As you can mark out that this rule is basically finding `RewriteBase` dynamically by comparing `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1`. An example of `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/directory/foobar.php` and example of `$1` for same example URI will be `foobar.php`. The difference in these 2 variables i.e. `/directory/` is captured as `\1` OR `%1` and used in setting up env variable `%{BASE}` i.e. `E=BASE:%1`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I am working with PHP 5.2.6 and Nowdoc was introduced in 5.3, but I could still tweak the ZF source to use `\\2` if that is in fact what they intended. I have updated my question to try and confirm what `\2` would actually mean in that context.

Comment: Yes I did mention in my answer that Heredoc requires you to double escape **Problem is that in Heredoc `\2` needs to be used as `\\2`**. I will add an explanation of what this `\2` is doing in your rule.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your answer with such a clear and concise explanation. I had an inkling that `\2` was yet another type of backreference but I was unable to find a source for that. Much appreciated!